# http call response header returning null in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

**IOnic serve case:**
when i run **ionic serve** http call return null in response header. i need headers to send in every next call for secure authentication. but Api returning null in response header when i call login http call.

**Ionic run android case:**
 But another case is when i run **ionic run android**  it give me response header in login call but right after the login call when i call next http call it returns null in response header of next call.

**Here is my Login code:**

```
 Login(email, password) {

        let body = JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password});
        //HTTP POST CALL FOR LOGIN 
        return this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, body, {headers: this.contentHeader}).subscribe(response => {

            if (response) {

                console.log('in login if');
                console.log(response.headers.get('uid'));
                console.log(response.headers.get('client'));
                console.log(response.headers.get('access-token'));

          this.uid = response.headers.get('uid');
          this.client =  response.headers.get('client');
          this.access_token =  response.headers.get('access-token');

//saving header for next call
  Save_Header(this.access_token, this.client, this.uid );


            } else{
              // login failed
              console.log("coming in........");
              this.error = 'Something went wrong';
              //  this.loading = false;
            }
    }
```

**Here is function which saving headers for next call:**

```
Save_Header(access_token,client, uid){
        this.contentHeader.append('access-token', access_token);
        this.contentHeader.append('client', client);
        this.contentHeader.append('uid', uid);
       //console.log(this.contentHeader);
    }
```

**function for getting header for next call:**

```
   Get_Header(){
    return this.contentHeader;
}
```

**Next http call:**

```
Get_All_Delivered_orders(){
        console.log("in userservice all delivered orders")
        console.log(this.Get_Header());
       return this.http.get(URL,{headers: this.Get_Header()});// getting saved headers
    }
```

what will be the problem ,in implementation or in Api?
please guide thanks!

Comment: If it is a CORS situation you need to set `Allow-access-expose-headers`, otherwise the headers won't be exposed to JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: we disabled the  CORS. what will be the other option?
Api responding fine like in Postman, but not responding correctly as described in question.

Comment: What do you mean with "disabled the CORS"? I don't know postman but I know that you also can see such response headers in the network tab of Chrome devtools just fine, you still won't be able to access them from JS.

Comment: I have allowed all origins (*) for CORS

Comment: It works well in JS But NOT with ionic serve. I tried XHR. 
```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("email", "test@example.com");
data.append("password", "password");


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://192.168.10.10:4000/api/v1/auth/sign_in");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "edbd7381-9c91-5dfe-bdc3-2619b7a09e4e");

xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: That's not about `allow-origins`, it's about `expose-headers`. Sorry, I didn't notice the `ionic2` tag. I don't know about Ionic.

Comment: okay thanks @Gunter

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, it is necessary to send the header:
Access-Control-Expose-Headers

```
      response.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'access-token, client, uid');
```

It is only necessary when the origin is different from the server. For example, from localhost:4200 to localhost:3000.